# rounding decimal to special number of digits

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create a function which rounds decimal numbers like this:

Round("$32.95", 0) to -> $33
Round("85.86%", 1)  to -> 86.9%

where first parameter is string and second parameter is number of decimal points required

I am using Math.round but it is converting to 85.9

Comment: You _want_ `85.86` converted to `86.9`? (Or do you just mean it's dropping the '%'?)

Comment: But 85.86 rounded to 1DP is 85.9, not 86.9??

Comment: Why would you want to 'round' 85.86 to 86.9?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Is it about rounding a number inside a string while retaining the rest of the string or is it really about rounding 85.86 to 86.9. (which would be a very unusual form of rounding to say the least)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An algorithm you can use (I don't know C#):

- get 10-to-the-power(number-of-significant-digits) (=P10)
- multiply your decimal-number by P10
- add:  0.5
- divide the integer-portion of this sum by (P10) - the answer will be your rounded number

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string into double and Pass it into Math.Round in a similar way shown below:

```
double num=32.86;
Math.Round(num);   //Output 33
Math.Round(num, 1) //Output 32.9
```